# datapoints with datetime x axis in asp.net chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-visualization, mschart

I am working on asp chart control.

I need to impletment datapoints in my chart having x axis with datetime data.

I go to datapoint concept (not in too deep) but found that it gets only

double

value. My question is how can i assign my datetime values to datapoint on x axis???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try assigning a valid datasource with `DateTime` property to the Chart. you can set the XValueType property like

```
Chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date; // or ChartValueType.DateTime
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Was this what you were looking for ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to set it to the `DateTime.ToOADate`.  This will make it a double that the chart can understand.

Documentation on using DateTimes in the Chart Controls library can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456614(v=vs.100).aspx